# XHTML & CSS: One of more <div>-tags won't use a background-image

Tags: css, xhtml, background-image

### My case

I am trying to put together a website with XHTML, CSS and JavaScript.
The document will use .png-images as their background,
not basic background color,
as that won't give the result I'm looking for.

### My issue

Inside the body-tag of my page, I divide sections of my code with the division-tag.
There are two divisions that, with CSS, uses .png-images as their background,
but a 3rd division simply won't use it's specified background-image property.

Here's my code:

```css
#bottomContainer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  /* This will indeed work. But then again, this is not what I want. */
  /* background-color: #89cff0; */
  /* This works in other < div>-elements, and it should work here as far as I see it. */
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/800/25");
}
```

```html
<div id="bottomContainer">
  This
  &lt;div&gt; simply won't take a .png-image as background-image...
</div>
```

### Conclusion

I must be overlooking something, either in the url, or another snare that
I can't see by myself.
Other division-elements will take the property,
therefore this must be a result of lack of
knowledge or experience.

*In advance; thank you for your time and guidence.*

Comment: I created a snippet from your code. The background-image shows.

Comment: @connexo I added "This &lt;div&gt; simply won't take a .png-image as background-image..." inside the division with "bottomContainer" as ID, and it worked!

But now I am severely confused.
How come I can use the background-image in other divisions and have them work just fine, but for this division, I needed your your code snippet? Who don't I need this snippet in my other divisions?

Comment: You probably confused the browser by not properly encoding `<` as `&lt;` and `>` as `&gt;`. The browser may have interpreted your unencoded `< div>` as `<div>` and thus, you would have a missing `</div>`.

Comment: And I say, l we'll need to see the original page before we can draw any conclusions. There are too many factors that can influence things. Anyway, your page is not XHTML.

Comment: @Mr Lister Thanks for letting me know.
I have been following XHTML tutorials.
Could you please let me know which version of HTML it is, then?

The DOCTYPE goes like so:
**<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">**

Comment: @OleKristianMøller-Hansen You can't really say that an HTML file with an HTML doctype declaration has a version, but this is most like HTML 4 in standards mode.

Comment: @Mr Lister Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Ehm, I was trying to say "with an XHTML doctype declaration", sorry. Typo. Anyway, we still haven't solved the problem; can you point us to the page you've made? Is it online yet? Otherwise, make a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @Mr Lister It is online: [link](ole.wask.org).
You have to adjust the viewport to 800 x 600,
otherwise the document is going to look like a nightmare.

Also, it is not written in english, but the functionality of the page is visible.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of @media queries. But I see that the problem is solved already; so, case closed?

Comment: @Mr Lister Yes, but I can't accept the answer. The problem is solved,
but this has not been answered, only commented on.

Comment: @OleKristianMøller-Hansen If you remember what exactly you changed to make it work, you can post an answer of your own, detailing the changes, and accept it.